# unable to parse csv if contains " "

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file with below values :

10~30~"mapping~~values"~40~50

when i try to parse this csv with delimiter ~

iam getting the values like :

10,30,mapping, ,values,40,50

but the actual result should look like :

10,30,mapping~~values,40,50 (when anything is enclosed in double quotes it should take a total value)

can any one please help me in this regard.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use the `opencsv` library which is lightweight and performant.

Comment: what are you using to parse the csv?

Comment: below is the code i am using

 String line = null;
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
    csvFilePath)); 
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.toString();
    csvRecords.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(delimiter)));
  
  }

Comment: Why do you not split the line using first " like a delimiter and add each element to an Array of String, lets say A, after that you loop over A and verify if the string doesn't contain ~~ so split it using ~ like a delimiter and add each element to Array B else if the string from  A  contains ~~ then add it to B

Comment: Clarify your question by editing it, not by adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

While CSV files look simple, they are quite complex as they need to handle cases where the delimiter is part of a value (using quotes as you observed in your case) or even when quotes appear in a string (typically encoded as double quotes). Thus, a simple String.split is not enough to parse CSV files.
There are several libraries that provide CSV readers, use one of those. Examples are the mentioned openCSV, or the one from Apache: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Suppose `line` is a line from a CSV file. The following code will split it correctly into items:

```
String[] items = line.trim().split(',(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)')
```